# Adding constraint programmatically gives me error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to add a left and right `NSLayoutConstraint` to a `view` programmatically. Here is my code:

```
[self.mainView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-2.5-[_otherView]-2.5-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(self.otherView)]];
```

I get the following error when I run the app:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format: 

_otherView is not a key in the views dictionary.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument to `NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings` should be `_otherView`.

It needs to be an exact string match to the way you refer to it in the constraint visual format.